# Parse markdown to HTML and highlight code syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, markdown, syntax-highlighting

I've downloaded a [Markdown JS library](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js) but I don't know if it supports syntax highlighting, or any of his two supported dialects (gruber/maruku), because its the first time I try to add markdown support to my webpages. So, I would like to know how to integrate a syntax highlighter (like [Alex Gorbatchev's JS library](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/)) to markdown.

Any other libraries are welcome. Basically, my Markdown snippets are in `.md` files loaded that way:

```
<div class="markdown-f">
   <?= file_get_contents("file.md"); ?>
</div>
```

and it contains code snippets together with common Markdown text. I need a JS library to be able of doing something like:

```
<script>
   $('.markdown-f').each(function() {
        var contents = $(this).text();
        $(this).empty();
        contents = markdown.toHTML(contents);
        $(this).text(contents);
   });
</script>
```

with a dialect or any other *hacktrick* supporting syntax highlighting (specifying manually the target language for example).

Answer (score 1):

I've used that markdown parser on [my website](http://jaredbeachdesign.herokuapp.com/projects/Tumblr%20Slide%20Show) to display the README files of repos I've created. It wraps code blocks in `<pre><code> code goes here </code></pre>`

It does not use highlighting, but you could then use the other library you mentioned after calling:

```
$("code").addClass("brush: js") // assuming you want to highlight javascript
```

Comment: What if I have different snippets in different languages?

Comment: Then the javascript for adding the class will have to be tailored to the different markdown files.

Comment: For example: `$($("code")[0]).addClass("brush: js"); $($("code")[1]).addClass("brush: py");`

Answer (score 1):

Finally I used [highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/usage/).

The @A.OzanEkici solution has the (little) downside that I lost the markdown highglighting of my text editor (the emacs's `markdown-mode`), since the contents inside the `<pre>` tag must be un-indent to don't see the indention in the rendered page, and the @JaredBeach doesn't work either because  Alex Gorbatchev's library only work on `<pre>` tags, not on `<pre><code>` tags, which is what is replaced by the markdown syntax.

So, my solution was simply:

```
<script>
   $('.markdown-f').each(function(){
      $(this).html(markdown.toHTML($(this).text()));
   });

   hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
</script>
```

And that has the adventage that the language is automatically detected.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Alex Gorbatchev's JS library](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) to do this and it works great.

First you should create a `<pre>` element like this;

```
<pre class="brush: __yourFileType__"> + data + </pre>
```

`data` refers to your `contents` and `__yourFileType__` can be [one of these](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/brushes/) .

Ex: `class="brush: xml" , class="brush: txt"`

After that you just simply call it;

`SyntaxHighlighter.highlight();`

Comment: But can I insert html elements inside a markdown text? And in that case I cannot use the indent syntax to specify code blocks isn't it?

Comment: Of course you can insert html elements. @Peregring-lk

Comment: @Peregring-lk You can see an example [here](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/demo/) .